# Регулярные выражения java, создание своего pattern

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! По учебе, выдали задание, в котором нельзя использовать встроенный в java метод pattern и требуется создать свой обработчик регулярных выражений. Задание звучит так:
Парсер, использующий простые регулярные выражения, вводимые с клавиатуры, содержащие управляющие конструкции . – любой символ, * - 0 и более символов, + - 1 и более символов (вводится регулярное выражение и строка, результатом является позиция, с которой это выражение встречается в тексте)

Matcher для поиска в тексте использовать можно. Буду рад ссылкам по теме создания своего обработчика регулярных выражений.

Comment: на скорость работы ограничения есть? и скобок точно не будет?

Comment: @pavel ограничений нет, разве что суть всего задания это unit тестирование, но там не критична скорость прохождения. Скобок не будет.

Comment: а можете пример с + и * тут они связаны с символом или сами по себе?

Comment: @pavel они связанны с символом. colou*r color, colour, colouur и т. д. colou+r - colour, colouur и т. д. (но не color)

Answer (score 1):

Весьма известная реализация подобного поиска. Для вашей задачи можно даже убрать ряд проверок. Если нужен +, то замените его просто на предыдущий символ и звёздочку. `a+ -> aa*` Код на С++ но легко переносится на Java (используется только индексация в строке).

```
// Формат регулярного выражения.
// c     Соответсвует любой букве "с"
// .(точка)  Соответсвует любому одному символу
// ^     Соответсвует началу входящей строки
// $     Соответствует концу входящей строки
// *     Соответствует появлению предыдущего символа от нуля до
//       нескольких раз

int matchhere(char *regexp, char *text);
int matchstar(int c, char *regexp, char *text);

// match: поиск соответствий регулярному выражению по всему тексту
int match(char *regexp, char *text)
{
  char * save = text;
  if (regexp[0] == '^')
    return matchhere(regexp+1, text);
  do { /* нужно посмотреть даже пустую строку */
   if (matchhere(regexp, text))
     return text - save;
  } while (*text++ != '\0');
  return -1;
}

// matchhere: поиск соответствий регулярному выражению в начале текста
int matchhere(char *regexp, char *text)
{
   if (regexp[0] == '\0')
     return 1;
   if (regexp[1] == '*')
     return matchstar(regexp[0], regexp+2, text);

   if (regexp[0] == '$' && regexp[1] == '\0')
     return *text == '\0';
   if (*text!='\0' && (regexp[0]=='.' || regexp[0]==*text))
     return matchhere(regexp+1, text+1);
   return 0;
}

// matchstar: поиск регулярного выражения вида с* с начала текста
int matchstar(int c, char *regexp, char *text)
{
  do {   /* символ * соответствует нулю или
            большему количеству появлений */
    if (matchhere(regexp, text))
      return 1;
  } while (*text != '\0' && (*text++ == c || c == '.'));
  return 0;
}
```

---

Код не мой, поэтому ответ общий.